# Ansible - convert a comma delimited string into a space delimited string with double quotes

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Following the great help I got for my last question I have another :).

I have a requirement to convert the contents of the string variable:  Targets

```
debug:
  msg:
    - "Targets: {{ targets }}"
```

Returns the following:

```
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": [
        "Targets: 10.0.1.1,10.0.1.2"
```

I need to be able to split the targets string and change it to a space delimited string, with each element encapsulated with a double quote.  This will then be passed to another command as a parameter.

**Updated for context**.
I am passing the targets variable to a role which in turn launches an executable:

```
- import_role:
    name: run_exectable_file
  vars:
    # passing all the params here.
    - params: -a -b -c {{ targets }}
    - runtime: 3600
```

The executable command line needs to be:

```
executable.exe -a -b -c "10.0.1.1" "10.0.1.2"
```

**Desired output:**

The targets variable need to produce the target IP addresses in a space delimited string, with each element encapsulated with a double quote.

For example, the following debug output:

```
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": [
        "Targets: "10.0.1.1" "10.0.1.2""
```

I look forward to your help as always.

Comment: Can you show us the context in which you'll be using the value (e.g., the `command` task or other task in which you'll be providing the generated value as a parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jinja to get what you want. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Targets: {{ _targets }}"
      vars:
        _targets: |
          {% for i in targets.split(',') %}"{{ i }}" {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Targets: "10.0.1.1" "10.0.1.2"
```

Comment: Looking closely, it's really quite simple (not that I could figure it out).  For loop over the split, create the string **"{{ i }}"**,  end loop.